# Error: iterator in view rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

When more than 7 items i need add class in the rest of items. This class is

```
.disp-none{
    display:none
}
```

and I want remove class when i click in button 'Ver mas'

```
%h4.section-header.section-header-vendors.bold Marcas principales
%table
  %tbody
    - for i  in (0..@vendors.length-1) do
      - if i <= 7
        %tr
          %td=link_to @vendors[i].name, @vendors[i], :class => 'color-nav-link'
      -else
        %tr
          %td=link_to @vendors[i].name, @vendors[i], :class => 'disp-none color-nav-link'
    %a{:href => "#", :id => 'dropdown_vendors'} Ver mas
```

I use this script in jquery

```
$('a').on 'click', '#dropdown_vendors', (event) ->
  $('tr td.disp_none').removeClass 'disp_none'
```

but when I click in 'Ver mas' not shown other elements

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. Is it that all of the vendors have the `disp_none` class applied?

Comment: No, the first 7 don't have this class, the rest if